# Bad magic number in super-block ... contains a ntfs file system labelled 'Σ'

Tags: mount, xubuntu, hard-drive, ntfs, drive

I used Greek letters for my volume labels which made it unnecessarily difficult to navigate via terminal. However, when I try to rename them I get the following error:

```
sudo e2label /dev/sdb1 "new_name"

e2label: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1 contains a ntfs file system labelled 'Σ'
```

I can't rename them via the mount properties menu either! I am not smart. Learn from my mistake. Do not use greek letters as volume labels...

Distro: Xubuntu 18.04

DE: XFCE

Comment: Are you sure the issue is not that you're trying to use `e2label` (which is for ext2/3/4 partitions) rather than (for example) `ntfslabel`? AFAIK `parted`/ `gparted` should also work.

Comment: I was not sure. Thanks for the tip. I've edited the post with the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have been using ntfslabel instead of e2label.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdb1 "new_name"
```